Conditional Formatting - Not applying to all cells
I am working with 3 columns. In column C cells 8 to 180 I have it setup as a list that I can select the status to show "done". I have column D which I use to wrong my tasks in and one conditional format setup to do a strikethrough if column C is marked "done". I have setup column M to bring over the text from column D depending on the outcome of column I. This works great, so here's the problem. In Column M, I need conditional formatting to do a strikethrough if any cell from M10:M180 matches any cell from D8:D180 only if the adjacent cell in Column C says "Done" How can I accomplish this?
This is the current formula I'm trying:
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(M10, $D$8:$D$180, 0)), C8="done")

and it works great on the first cell in column M but it doesn't work after that, and I've applied it in conditional formatting to $M10:$M$180.
The end result needs to be if it matches in column M and D and column C says "Done" in the appropriate cell, then it needs a simple strikethrough
